# Multiple textbox for search results

Tags: php

Hello I have a page with multiple textboxes, each textbox should search with its own query. Im using the following php code for this:

**php**

```
if ($val != null){
    $where = " WHERE boekingsnummer LIKE '".$val."%'";  
    }
```

How can I get it to work with the other textboxes ?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: the other textboxes are "boekingsnummer" also right? Can you post a sample entry of boekingsnummer from your db?

Comment: No im sorry if I was not clear, im using differend textbox names so no duplictes

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
$where = " WHERE 1 = 1 ";  
$where .= "AND boekingsnummer LIKE '".$val."%' ";
$where .= "AND ?? LIKE '".$val2."%' ";
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, could you try to explain your advise to me what it means, im having a hard time understanding your advise.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
$sql_add= '';
if ($val1 != '')
{
   $sql_add = " AND boekingsnummer LIKE '".$val1."%'";  
}  
if ($val2 != '')
{
   $sql_add .= " AND field2 = '".$val2."%'";  
} 
and so on....

$sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE 1=1 $sql_add";
```

may this will help you

Comment: Thank you im trying to implement this into my code. Could you explain wat '$sql_add= '';' stands for since im relatively new ?

Comment: @user3541335: it's a variable $where, which you have used, i have just replaced it with $sql_add and initially i m just assigning blank value to $sql_add

Comment: Owh thank I understand that part now, could you tell me why you leave it empty, is that te same as giving it the NULL value ?